# How can I center the children of a Wrap Widget while maintaining a grid-like structure?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The `Wrap` widget allows us to center its children using its `alignment` property.

```
|   widget widget   |
|   widget widget   |
|   widget widget   |
|       widget      | <--- problem
```

However, the effect I would like looks like this:

```
|   widget widget   |
|   widget widget   |
|   widget widget   |
|   widget          |
```

or

```
|    wid wid wid   |
|    wid wid       |
```

I do not want to use a `GridView` because the number of columns should vary depending on the size of the device. The same applies to having to manually use a set of `Row`s. I need to just be able to pass a list of widgets and have them aligned like in the examples above.

I also need the widgets to be centered because otherwise I get something like this:

```
|widget widget     |
|widget widget     |
|widget widget     |
|widget            |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Row` layout for each row and a `Center` layout or `Column` layour as parent.
For each `Row` layout you can add these properties

```
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
```